# DFS Greedy Chromatic Number

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, greedy

In my school I learned that calculating chromatic number of a arbitrary graph is NP-Complete.
I understand why the greddy algorithm does not work, but what about DFS/Greedy algorithm? 
The main idea is do a DFS an for all the vertex not yet colored, take the minimum color index over all the neighbours.

I can't figure out a counter example and this question is blowing my mind. 
Thanks for all of your answers.

Pseudocode

```
Chromatic(Vertex x){
    for each neighbour y of vertex x
        if color(y) = -1
           color(y) <- minimum color over all the neighbours of y
           if(y>=numColor) numColors++;
           Chromatic(y);
}
Main(){
  Set the color of all vertex equal -1
  Take an arbitrary vertex u and set color(u) = 0
  numColors = 1;
  Chromatic(u);
  print numColors;
}
```

Comment: You probably mean "color(y) := the smallest of the colors not used by the neighbors of y", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that sometimes you will have a vertex which has 2 colors available, and making the wrong choice will cause a problem an undetermined time later.

Suppose you have vertices 1 through 9.  Draw them around a circle.  Then add edges to make the following true.

1, 2, 3 form a triangle.
3 connects to 4.
4, 5, 6 make a triangle.
5, 6, 7 make a triangle.
6, 7, 8 make a triangle.
7, 8, 9 make a triangle.
8, 9, 1 make a triangle.
9, 1, 2 make a triangle.

It is easy to color this with 3 colors.  But a depth-first greedy algorithm has a choice of 2 colors it can give to vertex 4.  Make the wrong choice, and you'll wind up needing 4 colors, not 3.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a concrete counterexample: the [petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph). Your algorithm computes 4, regardless of where you start (I think), but the graph's chromatic index is 3.

[image]

The petersen graph is a classical counterexample for many greedy attempts at graph problems, and also for conjectures in graph theory.